# Why is there no compressor for DCL Implode?

Tags: compression, pkware

Why is there no open source implementation of the PKWare Data Compression Library's Implode? This is compression method 10, not 6.

There are many versions of decompressors. Is it very hard to do the reverse and write a compressor? I'm interested in the answer before I attempt it myself.

In answer to the question of why, it's because I need to transfer data in both directions and I can not use a newer method due to legacy limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be very hard to modify a deflate compressor to produce DCL compressed data. You're not finding it because there has not been any interest in it. It is an obsolete compressor.